# Calling SpringMvc Jsp Form In FancyBox

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc, fancybox

I am trying to get a jsp form into fancybox my site functions ok so i know most of my configurations are correct. I also did a sample test with an image and it worked great however with a form i am having problems. Under is the code:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
            <%@ include file="../js/lightbox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"%>

    </script>


    <style>
            <%@ include file="../js/lightbox/jquery.fancybox.css" %>

    </style>    

  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
        });
    </script>


  <title><fmt:message key="title"/></title>



  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><fmt:message key="heading"/></h1>
    <p><fmt:message key="greeting"/></p>


    <a href="<c:url value="login.htm"/>">Login</a></br>



    <a href="<c:url value="officer_registration.htm"/>">Register</a></br>


    <a class="fancybox" href="officer_registration.htm">Light Box Registration</a></br>
    <a class="fancybox" href="http://en.gtwallpaper.com/fondecran/chiens/chiens_01.jpg" >dog</a>


   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add data-fancybox-type="iframe" to the link, 
this will put an iframe within the fancybox displaying the href you passed through.